# HTTPGET fail when passing C# entity class to json-jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, web-services, json

**Here's my jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/services/Service.asmx/FamilyHistory',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            userID: 10,
            historyID: famid
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(val) {
            var famHist = val.d;
            alert(famHist.ID);
        },
        error: function() {
            parent.$.jGrowl('<b>Failed</b>',
                 {
                     header: 'User Action:',
                     life: 3000
                 });
        }
    });
```

**My Class:**

```
public sealed class FamilyHistoryEntity
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string RelativeName { get; set; }
}
```

**My Web service:**

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public FamilyHistoryEntity FamilyHistory(int userID, string historyID)
    {
         return GetFamilyHistory(historyID, userID); // returns a FamilyHistoryEntity class
    }
```

Problem is, i can't even make it do a breakpoint onto the webservice, it just throws the jquery ajax event of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the stringify function? It would seem like it is looking to call a method with a string parameter rather than the two parameters you have for your method.

Maybe I am missing something?

EDIT: So you would change  the data property to:

```
data: { userID: 10, historyID: famid },
```

Especially since you specify the contentType as json.

Comment: we need to stringify the json to pass a parameter to asp.net webservice.

Comment: @Martin ok. So are we certain that famid is a string variable and not an int?

Comment: ok the data part worked, it got through the webservice. but when it's returning the value, jquery's throwing a error event. do i need to [Serialize] the C# class?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting in your function? You shouldn't have to serialize the class.

Comment: definitely not coming from my webservice, it's returning correct data. would specific datatypes factor from c# to javascript? like DateTime? (nullables)

Comment: can you try adding the error parameters to the error function and then see what the error message is:

error:function (xmlHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, error){
                    alert(xmlHttpRequest.status);
                    alert(error);
                }

Comment: I got a "200" on the xmlHttpRequest.status and "undefined" on the error event.

Comment: Can you post the response that came back from the server? You should be able to inspect the xhr object to see.

Comment: the xhr.responseText returns a well formed xml. shouldn't it return an array because its json? am i missing something else?

Comment: I fixed it. I gave up on HTTPGEt and used HTTPPOST instead. thanks man