# asp.net webservice returning XML instead of Json object

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, json, asmx

[HTTPGET fail when passing C# entity class to json-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386398/httpget-fail-when-passing-c-entity-class-to-json-jquery)

my problem is, its returning an XML on its xhr.responseText rather than a Json object.

HELP!

Comment: Fixed! I used HTTPPOST instead of HTTPGET

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I used HTTPPOST instead of HTTPGET